# Showing results from Mysql Query that don't exist in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to request records from the user database that DO NOT match any entries in my interest table. Unfortunately either ALL records are shown, or No records are shown.

I have tried multiple mysql queries.

User Table

```
+------+-----------------+
| id   | username        |
+------+-----------------+
| 1200 | gordotheweirdo  |
| 1203 | emilly          |
| 1204 | belinda         |
| 1205 | dannbonadouchie |
+------+-----------------+
```

Interest table

```
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| p_interest_source | p_interest_target | p_interest_loser |
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
| 1204              | 1205              | 1200             |
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Simple Statement I've tried.

```sql
select *
from users
left join interested
  on users.id = interested.p_interest_source
where interested.p_interest_source <> 1204
  AND interested.p_interest_target <> 1205;
```

In the tables below, what should return for me is everyone in the user table except for id 1205 because they are found as a target in the Interest Table with 1204 being the source.

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: With that query, user 1205 will always show up; however that query will omit any result where 1204 targets 1205... if 1204 targets 1205 and only 1205, 1204 will be omitted entirely. Also keep in mind that null comparisons without special handling evaluate as null; so your conditions turn your left join into an inner join, which is why you are not getting the other users in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select u.*
from users u
left join interested i
  on  i.p_interest_target = u.id
  and i.p_interest_source = 1204
where i.p_interest_target is null
```

The JOIN will search for matches of the user ID in the `p_interest_target` column, but only with rows, where `p_interest_source = 1204` (Note that this condition must be in the ON clause). With `where i.p_interest_target is null` only unmatched rows from the users table are returned.

You can also get the same with a NOT EXISTS subquery:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (
  select *
  from interested i
  where i.p_interest_target = u.id
    and i.p_interest_source = 1204
)
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hGM4Ar3jLg4FD2ASckde1s/0)

Comment: @forpas No.. I edited the OP code. Using `u` and `i` as aliases is obvious.

Comment: No, you edited my answer with a fiddle. I restored now. See the edited in my answer.

Comment: @forpas I got what you mean now. Sorry! :-)

Comment: No worries. I restored it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from users
left join interested
  on users.id = interested.p_interest_source
where 
  interested.p_interest_source is null
  or interested.p_interest_source <> 1204 AND interested.p_interest_target <> 1205;
```

The thing is that you're doing a left join, so on every row that doesn't satisfy the join condition you have `NULL` in all columns of the joined table. And `NULL` is neither equal nor not equal to other values, so conditions like these will never be true for these rows:

```
interested.p_interest_target <> 1205
```